# convert elements in list to nested lists in list

Tags: python-3.7

I have a list which is needed to be converted to nested lists in a list

```
my_list = [2,5,6,7,8,15,34,56,78]
```

I need list as

```
final_list = [[2,5,6],[7,8,15],[34,56,78]]
```

I wrote code using for loop with length command and range command, I know there is error with range function, but I couldn't figure it out.

```
my_list = [2,5,6,7,8,15,34,56,78]
max_split = 3
final_list = [[len(my_list) for _ in range(max_split)] for _ in range(max_split)]
print(final_list)
```

But the output I get is `[[9,9,9],[9,9,9],[9,9,9]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code

```
my_list = [2,5,6,7,8,15,34,56,78]
max_split = 3
final_list = [my_list[i:i + max_split ] for i in range(0, len(my_list), max_split )]
print(final_list)
```

[**Demo**](https://repl.it/repls/OddballNonstopZip).

Answer (score 0):

If you use the indexes returned by the for loops, you can use them to count through the indexes in your list like this:

```
my_list = [2,5,6,7,8,15,34,56,78]
max_split = 3
final_list = [[my_list[i+3*j] for i in range(max_split)] for j in range(max_split)]
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 5, 6], [7, 8, 15], [34, 56, 78]]
```